# How to filter table in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django, search

I'm new to angularJS. I have tried this codes using html and it was working well but when I inserted this code to my django App, I can't get any data on my table

```
<script src="{% static "angularjs-1.4.3/angular.min.js" %}"></script>

<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
<table border="    <script src="{% static "angularjs-1.4.3/angular.min.js" %}"></script>

<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
<table border="1" id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{ friend.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ friend.phone }}</td>
  </tr>
</div>
</table>1" id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{ friend.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ friend.phone }}</td>
  </tr>
</div>
</table>
```

I believe I must have made a mistake with this syntax:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{ friend.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ friend.phone }}</td>
</tr>
```

I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Looks like you have some bad HTML. So, you might start by fixing all that's wrong with the markup :)

Comment: Alternatively, it  looks like something got really garbled when you copied your code in to SO, because I think I can see how it *should* go together, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aOb7lbJ8zSqn5rku46IL?p=info) but there are still some unresolved HTML errors like unexpected closing `</div>` tag etc.

Comment: This `<table border="    <script src="{% static "angularjs-1.4.3/angular.min.js" %}"></script>` seems like a very bad HTML.

Comment: Also, where's the js that corresponds to this model and controller? I've fixed the HTML to the best of my ability, but without your js,  `friends` should probably be part of the `ng-model` that you define in the js.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Angular variables inside django templates. Django uses symbol {{variable}} for rendering django variables. There are two workaround for this:

1. Either use angular variables inside django verbatim tag. Hence, your code will look like below :

> ```
> {% verbatim %}
> <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
> <td>{{ friend.name }}</td>
> <td>{{ friend.phone }}</td>
> </tr>
> {% endverbatim %}
> ```

2. Alternate solution is to use different symbol for angularjs variable which can be configured through Angularjs interpolation provider inside angular app.